# Java servlets on Tomcat take to 404 error but it works fine on localhost

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, http-status-code-404

I have design a webApp with NetBeans IDE. It works fine on localhost, but when I deploy it on my host, trying to access the servlets give me a 404 error.

My servlet dos include the URLpattern and the Name specifications, like this

```
@WebServlet(name = "FAQ", urlPatterns = {"/faq"})
public class FAQ extends HttpServlet {
```

The servlet just does a "redirection" to a .jsp

```
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/faq.jsp").forward(request, response);
        
    }
```

If I use the URL www.mysite/faq.jsp it works ok, but it doesn't when I try the servlet www.mysite/faq (even it does on localhost, as I said).

I have checked the .class files are compiled and included on the WEB-INF folder and it doesn't seme to be the problem.

Also I tried to add the web.xml description of the servlet like below, but it doesn't work either.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>FAQ</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>beans.FAQ</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>FAQ</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faq</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

I don't know waht could be my problem and it may be a very stupid thing, but I can't find it.

Thank you all.

Comment: Yes I tried. The problem doesnt't seem to be the servlet content, but the fact that the server can't find the servlet itself.

Comment: There is no problem with your code and configuration. There seems to be some problem with the configuration related to the host of your application. Did you check with your hosting provider?

Comment: They told me there is no problem with the hosting o the server configuration. They suggested me to check the classpath on compiling the app but I can't find what could be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

As I said, it should be a simple thing.
The hosting server was configurated on Tomcat 10x and JDK 10, while my project was build on jdk 8 and tomcat 7.
The solution was to ask for the hosting provider and change the server configuration to fit my project.